# Keyboard shortcut for blockquotes?

Tags: support, editor

Is there a keyboard shortcut to create a blockquote from selected text in the editor (similar like <kbd>CTRL-k</kbd> for code)?

I couldn't find any hint in the [editor help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup>There's also [no hint](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for the <kbd>CTRL-k</kbd> shortcut, I think this should be mentioned in the help.

Comment: Either hover over the blockquote symbol in the editor, *or start with Ctrl + * and start in the top left corner of the keyboard with Q and try each key till you find it ;)*

Comment: @Rizier123 THX.  Stupid me didn't associate *`''`* with blockquotes. Though shouldn't these shortcuts being mentioned in the editor help also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> or C-q. It's on the tooltip in the editor.