# Mention the available keyboard shortcuts for formatting posts in the editor help

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing-help

I think the available keyboard shortcuts to format selected text should be also mentioned in the editor [advanced help text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

> #### Code and Preformatted Text
>
> Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code> block:`
>
> ```
> printf("%d\n", 42);  /* what was the
>
>  question again? */
> ```

Add this:

> You can also select the code lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to indent four spaces.

Same (similar) for other keyboard shortcuts like

- Strong text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
- Emphasis (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
- Links (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Blockquotes (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)
- Images (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
- Runnable Snippets (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
- Numbered lists (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)
- Bulleted lists (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)
- Headings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Rulers (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Here's a not so old [related feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315159/why-are-the-editor-keyboard-shortcuts-not-documented?rq=1) (not a dupe, since there's mainly asked *why it's missing*, and it doesn't have a concrete proposal, how to document it).

Comment: Yes, why not make the help longer. Nobody ever reads it anyway. (BTW: They are documented in tooltips in the editor toolbar.)

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I know. If you know what to hover on the information is there. I was stupid enough to [check the help first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327872/keyboard-shortcut-for-blockquotes).

Comment: Even if nothing changes, this question itself is very useful.

Comment: I think this is definitely worth it because I did not know any of these. I have literally been hitting space 4 times every time I format someones code. How embarrassing...

Comment: @MattLishman - In the places where Ctrl+K doesn't work very well, you may want to consider copying the content into your favourite notepad/editor and then just hitting tab as required..

Comment: It would be easier for the brain to remember if you use  titles which correspond  to the shortcuts, like Bold(b), Italic(i), Quote (q), Graphic(g)? , MCVE(m), Ordered list(o), Unordered list(u). Maybe with the current titles as additional info (tooltip or something) if necessary.

Comment: @TJ: Snippets do not cleanly map to MCVEs, unfortunately; they are often MCVEs, but not always, and not all MCVEs by a vast margin are snippets.

Comment: What about the Mac shortcuts? (Not that the hover text mentions it either...)

Comment: Maybe we could follow what others do and show the shortcuts when pressing `Ctrl + ?`?

Answer (score 4):

The [Markdown help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) now includes keyboard hints:

> #### Code and Preformatted Text
>
> Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code> block:`
>
> ```
> printf("%d\n", 42);  /* what was the
>
>  question again? */
> ```
>
> You can also select text and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to toggle indenting as code.

(etc etc for  the  other keyboard hints)